# I need help combining a few select statements

Tags: sql, join, oracle10g

I would like to pull all of the columns from my second select statement and put it to the right of all of my columns from my first statement.

I have tried `Union` and the `join` commands with no luck. 
When I use these they just have what I wanted from my first select statement.

Here is basic code I have.

```
Select * from MTG_TREND where LINEID='A2' end;

Select * from MTG_TREND where LINEID='B2'
```

All of the other columns are the same.

Comment: How about trying UNION ALL?

Comment: You mean you want col1, col2, ... col1, col2, ...? What if different number of rows in the two tables?

Comment: You need to merge the tables, but since you can't have columns with same names you'll need to rename the columns for starters.  What flavour of SQL are you working with?

Comment: you should tag the dbms you're using

Comment: Yes I want col1,col2....col1, col2...there will be the same amount of rows in each table

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.*,t2.* from MTG_TREND t1 
left join (
           Select * from MTG_TREND where LINEID='B2'
) as t2
on t1.primarykey=t2.primarykey
where t1.LINEID='A2'
```

Comment: Thanks this looks great! Trying it out

Comment: I could not get this to work I am missing a expression.

Comment: unfortunately I am not an Oracle developer..so cant exactly convert my sql server answer into Oracle statement..but I am sure my simple logic if gets converted into oracle will give you desired output without any pivot..

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: 
- Make sure you are matching the same number of columns in both SELECT Statement. 
- Another thing to remember is you have to have the same matched column (datatype). 
- If there are some columns that are not present is the table then just defined the column with null so that you can get it in output from another select statement.

```
Select col1, col2, col3,...... from MTG_TREND where LINEID='A2' 
    UNION ALL    
Select col1, col2, col3,...... from MTG_TREND where LINEID='B2'
```

Comment: I think this will not work since.. OP needs to pull all of the columns from my second select statement and put it to the right .... last word is most important..

Comment: If that is the case, after the output you get from UNION ALL you can PIVOT to get your output

Comment: I'm using sql 10G With oracle  and my problem with the Union All is that it only takes first command how do you Pivot?